# Component unable to launch at an action

Tags: angular

I have two buttons in a component. Upon clicking these buttons two separate components should be launched but it is not the case. My component containing the buttons look like following.

HTML:

```
      <button class="btns" md-button (click)="goToConnect('Signup')">Sign Up</button>

      <button class="btns" md-button (click)="goToLogin('Login')">Log In</button>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And .ts file lloks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router }            from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing-page',
  templateUrl: './landing-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./landing-page.component.scss']
})
export class LandingPageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  goToConnect(title: string): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/connect', title]);
  }
  goToLogin(title: string): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/login', title]);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and my module router looks like this:

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ConnectComponent } from './components/connect/connect.component';
import { VerifyComponent } from './components/verify/verify.component';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './components/landing-page/landing-page.component';
import { SelectSignatureComponent } from './components/select-signature/select-signature.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { CreateDocComponent } from './components/dashboard/create-doc/create-doc.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { AuthGaurd } from './_gaurds/auth.gaurd';

const routes: Routes = [
  //{ path: '', redirectTo: '/connect', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '', component: LandingPageComponent },
  { path: 'login',  component: LoginComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'connect',  component: ConnectComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGaurd]},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'dashboard'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

On clicking both buttons i.e Signup and Login only connect component is launched.Any Idea where I am making mistake?

Comment: What is the use of the title variable in your "navigate" functions? When the router.navigate() function is provided with an array of values, they are concatanated with each other. So for instance if  you call goToLogin('hello'), the router would try to navigate to '/login/hello' which is not a defined route.

Comment: Thanks man! That was it!

Answer (score 0):

In your above example changing to:

```
  goToConnect(title: string): void {
    this.router.navigate(['connect']);
  }
  goToLogin(title: string): void {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }
```

Should work fine. Your current methods go to the paths `'/login/Signup'` and `'/login/login'` neither of which are defined in your `Routes`.